# Why does Twilio React application useEffect give a track.off is not a function error while unmounting?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, use-effect

I'm trying to develop an application based on [example Twilio React project on github](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react)

But when I click the toggle video button, it gives an error.

`Uncaught TypeError: track.off is not a function`
`The above error occurred in the <ToggleAudioButton> component:`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { LocalAudioTrack, LocalVideoTrack, RemoteAudioTrack, RemoteVideoTrack } from 'twilio-video';


export default function useIsTrackEnabled(track) {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(track ? track.isEnabled : false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsEnabled(track ? track.isEnabled : false);

    if (track) {
      const setEnabled = () => setIsEnabled(true);
      const setDisabled = () => setIsEnabled(false);
      track.on('enabled', setEnabled);
      track.on('disabled', setDisabled);
      return () => {
        track.off('enabled', setEnabled);
        track.off('disabled', setDisabled);
      };
    }
  }, [track]);

  return isEnabled;
}
```

```
export default function ToggleAudioButton(props) {
 
  const [isAudioEnabled, toggleAudioEnabled] = useLocalAudioToggle();

  const { localTracks } = useVideoContext();
  const hasAudioTrack = localTracks.some(track => track.kind === 'audio');

 
  return (
    
    <IconMicrophone onClick={toggleAudioEnabled} className="svg-icon" /> 
                 
  );
}
```

Why it's giving an error while unmounting the component?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Have you changed anything in the app? Can you describe the steps you take to cause this error? Thanks.

Comment: @philnash thank you for your answer.
I'm trying to integrate the example application in my current meteor.js application. 
I changed it from ts to jsx and yes I changed a lot of things in the code. I think when I'm modifying it, I missed some parts and it causes the error.
When the second participant connects the room, I can see this error on the side of the first participants. 
I checked there is no access to providers internal hooks from outside of the provider and when I was debugging I could see that *room* is not null and a twilio video object.

Comment: Are you definitely getting a `Track` object inside `useIsTrackEnabled` and not a `TrackPublication`? Are you able to log what the track object is so that we can tell what is happening when the error occurs?

Comment: @philnash this is what I got when I log the track object.

```LocalAudioTrack {kind: "audio", name: "4b602bc6-8ea8-4443-9ad4-
...
__proto__: LocalAudioTrack
```

Comment: What happens if you try `track.removeListener` instead of `track.off`?